# Azure Data Lake Gen2 (ADLS Gen2)

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to find ADLS Gen2 from my Azure account. But, I am not able to locate ADLS Gen2. This is the first time I am trying to use ADLS Gen2.

[image]

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Click on Storage Account and while creating the storage account, check on Heirarchial namespace, then you can create the adlsgen2, Then you can go to storage accounts to find by using name of it in search box.

Comment: hi , Go to storage account - > advance. You will find gen2 or refer this [link](https://i.imgur.com/KUHnf24.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys, I am able to find ADLS Gen2. Posting this answer if someone else have this question in future.

---

In the Storage Account:

[image]

---

Create a new storage and click on **Advanced**:

[image]

---

Then **Enable hierarchical namespace** in Advanced by clicking the checkbox.

[image]

Then proceed with other steps like Networking, etc. and complete the process.